# Fetch Specific field and cell value next to it based on a condition using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe and I want to fetch the value of the column and the cell value next to it in separate new columns. The condition is that I want only those shelves where item A and B are present and their respective selling price. For anything else it should fetch NA. I have given an example of the input and expected output. I tried various options like concatenating and using regular expression but couldnot achieve the desired result.

```
df_input <- data.frame (shelf_1  = c('A','A','B','C','C','D'),
                  selling_price_s1 = c(20000, 23000, 26000,25000,24000,20000),
                  shelf_2  = c('D','C','C','A','A','D'),
                  selling_price_s2 = c(23000, 25000, 25000,21000,22000,25000),
                  shelf_3  = c('C','D','D','C','NA','C'),
                  selling_price_s3 = c(20000, 23000, 26000,25000,NA,20000),
                  )

df_expected <- data.frame (shelf  = c('A','A','B','A','A','NA'),
                  selling_price = c(20000, 23000, 26000,21000,22000,NA),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_input)

df_input[, melt(.SD, measure = patterns("^shelf", "^selling_price_s"))
         ][value1 %chin% c("A", "B", "NA")]

   variable value1 value2
1:        1      A  20000
2:        1      A  23000
3:        1      B  26000
4:        2      A  21000
5:        2      A  22000
6:        3     NA     NA
```

PS. if you format your `NA` properly you need to add in `|is.na(value1)` in the last step.

Base R alternative:

```
df_out <- data.frame(
  shelf = as.character(unlist(df_input[grep("shelf", names(df_input))])),
  selling_price = unlist(df_input[grep("selling_price", names(df_input))], use.names = FALSE)
)
df_out
df_out[df_out$shelf %in% c("A", "B", "NA"), ]
```

Reproducible data:

```
df_input <- data.frame(
  shelf_1  = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'),
  selling_price_s1 = c(20000, 23000, 26000, 25000, 24000, 20000),
  shelf_2  = c('D', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D'),
  selling_price_s2 = c(23000, 25000, 25000, 21000, 22000, 25000),
  shelf_3  = c('C', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'NA', 'C'),
  selling_price_s3 = c(20000, 23000, 26000, 25000, NA, 20000)
)
```

Comment: thanks. But the base R alternative doesnt work. It just repeats the same values in both columns.

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```r
cols <- c("shelf", "value")
subset(rbind(setNames(df_input[1:2], cols), 
             setNames(df_input[3:4], cols), 
             setNames(df_input[5:6], cols)),
       shelf == "A" | shelf == "B" | shelf == "NA")) 

#>    shelf value
#> 1      A 20000
#> 2      A 23000
#> 3      B 26000
#> 10     A 21000
#> 11     A 22000
#> 17    NA    NA
```